# is there a way to reset a password via email without firebase auth in flutter

Tags: flutter, forgot-password

In case a user forgot their password, how can I send them an email to reset it without firebase authentication?

As in they receive an email with a link that takes them to a page/webpage where they can reset their password and confirm the change, then they can login with their new password.

Comment: Just curious but why are you not using Firebase authentication? It's pretty comprehensive and it's free.

Comment: well, here's my issue, I used firebase real time database to store each user's information (username, password, phone number etc.) and now I need to reset the password that exists in the database through email. However, if I use fb authentication, it will only take the email and password, so I really don't have any ideas on how to link each user in fb authentication with fb real time database? also, English isn't my first language so it's very hard for me to find useful resources or people that can help me.

Comment: You should not be storing the user password, or other sensitive info on FB RTDB, that is what firebase authentication is for. You should only be using the authenticated userid as the key to the user's other data on RTDB.

Comment: Firebase Authentication creates a unique userid for each user. It gives you all the necessary functions to manage the user login and security. You should then use the userid it created as your key to the user's less sensitive data  kept in RTDB. I use exactly this setup in my app.

Comment: I will work on it. Thank you so much for showing me the way!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Firebase Auth in your app: I don't know what you mean by "without firebase authentication?" That's not possible, but perhaps you mean through a specific means.  Here are the two most common ways:

You can manually send a password reset by going into your firebase dashboard, go to Authentication, find the email, and on the right of the UID a menu icon comes up when you hover..you can choose to send a password reset email.

You can call this in a flutter app  `FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);`